# Would a USB NIC work with Ubuntu Server 12.04.4 LTS?

Tags: 12.04, networking, server, usb, nic

I'd like to state first off that I'm new to Linux and am still learning the ropes.

I recently installed Ubuntu Server 12.04.4 LTS on a Dell PowerEdge 1800.  I also installed the Xfce 4 Desktop Environment.

I intend to install Clonezilla Server next.  However, the system only has an onboard NIC and I don't have any PCI NICs available.  I know that at a minimum two physical NICs are recommended when setting up a Clonezilla Server.

Will the Ubuntu Server operating system accept a USB NIC?

Answer (score 0):

I can't imagine why you wouldn't be able to. NIC is a NIC. As for it being PCI, technically everything is connected to a PCI location in the linux filesystem. Find out if you require a physical PCI slot which I doubt this is the case. Everything PCI will be listed under `lspci` which also include usb devices.

Unfortunately I have used Clonzilla Server myself so I cannot be 100% sure.

Comment: Thank you for answering Mr. Lee.  Should I re-install Unbuntu Server to have the USB NIC auto configured or is there an easier way to setup the USB NIC?

Comment: Check out the /etc/network/interfaces which is where you can set NIC settings. I'm not familiar with Clonesilla Server, is it a program on top of Ubuntu or an OS itself? It looks like it is independent of Ubuntu, so I am not sure why you mentioned Ubuntu Server. Also try typing `ip a` in the terminal to see if your card is recognized.